# Question about biased coin and Bayes' formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I toss a biased coin with 2/3 chance of landing on heads, given that there was at least one head in 3 flips, what is the probability that there is only 1 head?

Chance of head is 2/3, thus tails is 1/3.

In this question, I can use Bayes' formula that says:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)*P(B)}{P(A)}$$

If we let $X$ represent the amount of heads, then the formula becomes:

$$P(X \geq 1|X=1) = \frac{P(X=1|X \geq 1)*P(X = 1)}{P(X \geq 1)}$$

Well, for $P(X=1|X \geq 1)$, this is 100%, since if I am given that the number of flips is $\geq 1$, then of course $X = 1$ is 100%.

$P(X=1)$ can be expressed as P(Head)P(Tail)P(Tail)(Number of ways this can happen)

$$P(X=1) = (\frac{2}{3}) (\frac{1}{3})^2 (3) = \frac{2}{9}$$

$P(X \geq 1$).

$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X=0)$

$1 - P(X=0) = 1-(\frac{1}{3})^3 = \frac{26}{27}$

So, 
$$P(X \geq 1|X=1) = \frac{1*\frac{2}{9}}{\frac{26}{27}} = \frac{3}{13} = 23\%$$

---

My issue with this question is however, why can't I directly just calculate the probability of only landing 1 head? Why do I have to go through Bayes formula. Probability of landing 1 head only is just $\frac{2}{9}$. How I know what the right answer is? How is this any different then what I've shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any additional information changes the likeliness.

Consider for e.g. Tossing a coin (fair coin) 2 times.

Possible outcomes (Sample Space) = HH, TH, HT, TT
Event exactly one head = TH, HT
So Prob (Event exactly one head) = 2 / 4

Let me give you addition information about the outcome of the experiment
There was at least one HEAD.
Under the new information
Possible outcomes (Sample Space) = HH, TH, HT (Please note TT is no longer possible now under the new information)
Event exactly one head = TH, HT
So Prob (Event exactly one head) = 2 / 3
Mathematically we call/represent above as conditional probability i.e. Prob (Event exactly one head | There was at least one HEAD )

Hope that helps